# How can I open a saved website using browser offline mode?

Tags: firefox, browser, internet-explorer

I had opened a site and closed my browser (i.e. Firefox). After reopening, I have enabled offline mode to load the saved website, but the webpage can not be opened.
I remember Internet Explorer could open recently closed websites in offline mode. Does anyone know how to load recently closed websites in offline mode in Firefox?